# docker CLI registry login fails

Tags: docker, authentication, command-line-interface, docker-registry

On Ubuntu 16.04 and docker 1.12.6, I can't log into the default registry,  https://index.docker.io/v1. The response is:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

I can log into both hub and cloud with the account.

Has anyone had this problem and how did you solve it?

I sent a ticket to support, and they reset my password, without acknowledging that it's a specifically CLI login issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured this out. From the CLI engine, the username is exactly that, the username, not the email address. The hub and cloud allow email address as well as username for the login principal.

Comment: There's docker id, your email address, and a username, which you picked at account creation. Use the latter, as in: `docker login --username your-username-here`.